# Factory-Boy - KeyError: 'locale'

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests, factory-boy

Got following exception from `factory-boy` during running my pytests:

```sh
    def generate(self, params):
>       locale = params.pop('locale')
E       KeyError: 'locale'
```

How to solve that issue? Everything worked few days ago, my code wasn't changed.

Here is the code example of what :

```py
import factory
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    is_cheat = models.BooleanField()

class MyModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
    name = factory.Faker("name")
    is_cheap = factory.Faker("boolean")
    price = factory.Maybe("is_cheap", yes_declaration=factoryFaker("pyint", max_value=10), no_declaration=factory.Faker("pyint", min_value=100))
```

Answer (score 1):

In [faker.py](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/pull/785#issuecomment-703089052) I see that there is no default value in `.pop()`:

```py
def generate(self, params):
    locale = params.pop('locale')  # <-- Issue occurs here
    subfaker = self._get_faker(locale)
    return subfaker.format(self.provider, **params)
```

But not sure if it should be there. [Here is the comment](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/pull/785#issuecomment-703089052) of author of `factory-boy` with explanation of the situation.

Looks like there is a bug in `3.1.0`, **downgrading to `3.0.1` should help**. At least temporarily, while they haven't fixed that.

Comment: In my code, I just added some params to my call to `.generate()`, for example, `.generate({"locale": None})`.